# Search an element on a list

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I have a this list in my code:

```
def officers = [[name:'Mark', surname: 'Pen'], [name:'Maria', surname: 'Charlote']]
```

now is it possible to search this list? I mean something like

```
def found = officers.findNameLike('%Mar%')
```

and so it will return those 2 values since they have MAR char on their names.

Is it even possible? Or is their anyway around this?

Comment: It is a normal list, not an OR-Mapped class. You need to use regular Groovy code to search it, for instance with `officers.findAll`

Comment: regex is another option like `^[mar]$`

Comment: Is their any simple groovy code to search for it? Or do I need to create a bulky code to check its every element?

Comment: You need to create code to check its every element, but bulky it is not.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know Groovy, but by a quick Google, something non-bulky like this should work:

```
def found = officers.findAll { it.name =~ /Mar/ }
```